# playmidi /dev/sequencer not found

Tags: midi

```
playmidi midi.mid
```

Does not play, but gives the following error:

```
playmidi /dev/sequencer not found.
```

How can this be resolved?

By the way, I am using Ubuntu 10.10. Totem movie player does play midi files. I want to use playmidi to be able to select channels from the midi file. To my knowledge that is not possible with totem.

Update:
I followd Amith his suggestion.

```
sudo modprobe snd_hda_codec_atihdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_intel snd_seq_midi snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_rawmidi snd_pcm snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device snd soundcore snd_page_alloc
```

These are all modules that are listed in

```
lsmod |grep snd
```

Running playmidi gives the same error still.

Comment: I just linked /dev/sequencer to /dev/snd/seq with `ln /dev/snd/seq /dev/sequencer` and this will only work if your sound card supports midi.

Answer (score 1):

Do an lsmod in the terminal. It should return something like this

> ```
>  Module                  Size  Used by
>
> bnep                   17923  2 
> rfcomm                 38408  12 
> ip6table_filter        12711  0 
> ip6_tables             22528  1 ip6table_filter
> pci_stub               12550  1 
> vboxpci                22882  0 
> vboxnetadp             13328  0 
> vboxnetflt             27211  0 
> vboxdrv               251814  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
> ipt_MASQUERADE         12663  3 
> iptable_nat            13016  1 
> nf_nat                 24958  2 ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat
> nf_conntrack_ipv4      19084  4 iptable_nat,nf_nat
> nf_defrag_ipv4         12649  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
> xt_state               12514  1 
> nf_conntrack           70103  5 ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,xt_state
> ipt_REJECT             12512  2 
> xt_CHECKSUM            12493  1 
> iptable_mangle         12646  1 
> xt_tcpudp              12531  5 
> iptable_filter         12706  1 
> ip_tables              18106  3 iptable_nat,iptable_mangle,iptable_filter
> x_tables               21975  11 ip6table_filter,ip6_tables,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,xt_state,ipt_REJECT,xt_CHECKSUM,iptable_mangle,xt_tcpudp,iptable_filter,ip_tables
> bridge                 79567  0 
> stp                    12811  1 bridge
> ppdev                  12849  0 
> nvidia              10590610  40 
> btusb                  18160  2 
> snd_es1938             19610  3 
> gameport               15060  2 snd_es1938
> snd_opl3_lib           18863  1 snd_es1938
> snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_opl3_lib
> snd_mpu401_uart        13865  1 snd_es1938
> bluetooth             148839  23 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
> snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
> snd_intel8x0           33318  3 
> snd_ac97_codec        106082  1 snd_intel8x0
> ac97_bus               12642  1 snd_ac97_codec
> gspca_zc3xx            51066  0 
> gspca_main             27610  1 gspca_zc3xx
> snd_rawmidi            25241  2 snd_mpu401_uart,snd_seq_midi
> snd_pcm                80435  3 snd_es1938,snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
> videodev               85626  1 gspca_main
> snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
> snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
> snd_timer              28932  3 snd_opl3_lib,snd_pcm,snd_seq
> snd_seq_device         14172  4 snd_opl3_lib,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
> i915                  505159  1 
> snd                    55902  23 snd_es1938,snd_opl3_lib,snd_hwdep,snd_mpu401_uart,snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_rawmidi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
> soundcore              12600  1 snd
> snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
> drm_kms_helper         32889  1 i915
> drm                   192194  2 i915,drm_kms_helper
> parport_pc             32114  1 
> binfmt_misc            17292  1 
> i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
> video                  18908  1 i915
> w83627hf               26767  0 
> hwmon_vid              12658  1 w83627hf
> lp                     17455  0 
> parport                40930  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
> usbhid                 41905  0 
> hid                    77367  1 usbhid
> 8139too                23283  0 
> 8139cp                 22636  0 
> floppy                 60310  0
> ```

If you don't see any MIDI related modules (the important ones are snd_seq_midi,snd_emu10k1_synth,snd_emux_synth,snd_ seq_oss,snd_seq,snd_emu10k1,snd_rawmidi),
then that means ALSA hasn't been configured properly. Try `sudo modprobe` for these modules, and see what results.